# How to fix error on python django_auth_ldap

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a problem!

When I try to install django_auth_ldap on Windows x64, python 2.7 64. I get this error:

**Console Log**
after `pip install django_auth_ldap`

```
    C:\Users\Dmisss\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_SASL -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.5.2 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
    LDAPObject.c
    c:\users\dmisss\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-tcxk8h\python-ldap\modules\errors.h(7) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Dmisss\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
   Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\dmisss\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-tcxk8h\\python-ldap\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\dmisss\appdata\local\temp\pip-swbv4g-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\dmisss\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-tcxk8h\python-ldap\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of `django_auth_ldap`](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installation):

> Under Python 2, it requires python-ldap >= 2.0; under Python 3, it uses pyldap. **In either case, you’ll need the OpenLDAP libraries and headers available on your system.**

It seems you had missed the part for installing the **OpenLDAP libraries and headers**, as your error show here:

```
Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
```

Instructions to install `OpenLDAP` can be found here: https://www.openldap.org/software/release/install.html

Comment: i m download python-ldap https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap
install this package. 
After that, my installation django_auth_ldap was successful. Sorry for my english, hope you understood me

Comment: On Ubuntu, you will need to run this command: `apt install libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev`. You may also optionally need `python-dev` and `libssl-dev` if you don't already have those installed.