# Error in python-ldap django-auth-ldap packages

Tags: ldap, django-ldapdb

I am actually installing 'python-ldap' and  'django-auth-ldap' packages on windows system to integrate my application with LDAP But getting below error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's not supposed to be supported on Windows platform but you can find the (unofficial) binaries [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-ldap)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried downloading from the the page mentioned by you. While building It is still giving the same error.

Comment: sorry.. actually the error is well known and means you don't have the OpenLDAP libraries and headers available on your system. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768446/i-cant-install-python-ldap 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546886/how-to-fix-error-on-python-django-auth-ldap , once done you'll probably still need the proper .whl (the one you just downloaded)